# Remove [os-rot] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[os-rot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/os-rot) contains two questions.  One was a duplicate (of a question that didn't need the tag).  The other asked, "What is OS rot?" in response to the duplicate.  It appears to be unnecessary and not understood.

Comment: yeah, I'd just go ahead and remove them. Its a useless tag :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I just removed those tags, including the related questions which were just a huge collection of personal opinion about how everybody keeps their machine clean. Not really a form of question we'd encourage anymore.

Comment: Nice. Do you want to [status-complete] this question then?